# Wrapfigure on top right corner

Tags: wrapfigure, alignment, includegraphics

Hello I am using MikTex in TexStudios. I have this document:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectsty}        % Custom sectioning}{sectsty package)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%\addtolength{\voffset}{-40pt}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{20pt}

\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}



\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\NewPart}[2]{\section*{\uppercase{#1} #2}}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2cm, keepaspectratio=true]{batman.jpg}
    \end{wrapfigure}    
    {\noindent\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Wayne}}\\
    Address line 1\\
    Address line 2\\
    \href{mailto:yoloj@gmail.com}{yolo@gmail.com}\\
    %\sepspace
    \NewPart{Overview}{}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent volutpat sapien neque, id elementum turpis tincidunt sed. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque malesuada odio sit amet blandit commodo. Sed sed dolor massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin suscipit enim risus, id vehicula risus facilisis ac. Nullam et libero vitae mi viverra tincidunt vitae ac purus. Pellentesque ac justo et augue tincidunt maximus. Morbi velit metus, consectetur ac orci sit amet, gravida suscipit lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur est leo, rutrum eget laoreet at, imperdiet id velit. Phasellus dignissim mi sed lacus porttitor tempor et tempus justo. Aliquam at congue augue. Quisque sed velit ac neque tristique sagittis. 
    Relocation is NOT a problem.
    \NewPart{Skills}{}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
            \item 4
            \item 5
            \item 6
            \item 7
            \item 8
            \item 9
            \item 10
            \item 11
            \item 12
            \item 13
            \item 14
        \end{itemize}   
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I would like the picture to be on the top right side of the paper but within the text margins. The problem is that the wrapfigure offsets all the rules and the text behind it by a lot!

Expected result is:
[image]

What I get is:
[image]

Comment: Why are you even using wrapfigure for this? Does it extend into `overview`? If not just place it absolutely on the page or put bruce wayne in one minipage box and the inage in another. See also the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: mmm I don't know what an overview is. So you are suggesting to use minipage? Will I have to do some amendments to my doc apart from adding the minipage?

Comment: You have a section named "Overview" in your example.....

Comment: ah sorry, the lower case and the grey highlight made me think it was a LaTex concept. It should not extend into overview, that's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `wrapfigure` here as it is for running text, i.e. paragraphs, not for broken lines like this. You can fit in the image using `adjustbox`, which you load anyway. Just add a `\hfill` after the name to push the image to the right, then align the image using `adjustbox` keys vertically and/or horizontally and remove its official height and depth so that the image size is no longer taken into account for the line height etc.

Just replace the first lines with:

```
\begin{document}
    {\noindent\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Wayne}%
\hfill\adjustimage{height=2cm,valign=t,set height={0pt},set depth={0pt}}{example-image}%
}\\
```

I'm using `\adjustimage` here instead of `\includegraphics`, it however uses the same internals, but allows for better `adjustbox` integration. `valign=t` makes the vertical alignment according to the size of the name ("Bruce Wayne" here) and the `set ..` keys are for reducing its official size. If you need to have some white margin around use the `margin` key or maybe `center=<some width, not to wide>`, or `left=...` or `right=...`. See the `adjustbox` manual for a detailed description on these keys.

[image]
I replaced you Batman sign with a standard example image, to make the document compileable for me.

Answer (score 5):

`wrapfig` is not the right tool.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectsty}        % Custom sectioning}{sectsty package)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%\addtolength{\voffset}{-40pt}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{20pt}

\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}



\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\NewPart}[2]{\section*{\uppercase{#1} #2}}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  {\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Wayne}\\}
  Address line 1\\
  Address line 2\\
  \href{mailto:yoloj@gmail.com}{yolo@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}}

%\sepspace

\NewPart{Overview}{}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent volutpat sapien neque, id elementum turpis tincidunt sed. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque malesuada odio sit amet blandit commodo. Sed sed dolor massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin suscipit enim risus, id vehicula risus facilisis ac. Nullam et libero vitae mi viverra tincidunt vitae ac purus. Pellentesque ac justo et augue tincidunt maximus. Morbi velit metus, consectetur ac orci sit amet, gravida suscipit lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur est leo, rutrum eget laoreet at, imperdiet id velit. Phasellus dignissim mi sed lacus porttitor tempor et tempus justo. Aliquam at congue augue. Quisque sed velit ac neque tristique sagittis. 
    Relocation is NOT a problem.
    \NewPart{Skills}{}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
            \item 4
            \item 5
            \item 6
            \item 7
            \item 8
            \item 9
            \item 10
            \item 11
            \item 12
            \item 13
            \item 14
        \end{itemize}   
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- `utf8x` has been unmaintained for several years; use `utf8`
- loading `geometry` and then doing all page setup by hand doesn't seem efficient
- `sectsty` and `scrartcl` don't go along well

An edited version:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectsty}        % Custom sectioning}{sectsty package)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

\geometry{margin=1in,headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\NewPart}[2]{\section*{\uppercase{#1} #2}}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  {\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Wayne}\\}
  Address line 1\\
  Address line 2\\
  \href{mailto:yoloj@gmail.com}{yolo@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}}

%\sepspace

\NewPart{Overview}{}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent volutpat sapien neque, id elementum turpis tincidunt sed. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque malesuada odio sit amet blandit commodo. Sed sed dolor massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin suscipit enim risus, id vehicula risus facilisis ac. Nullam et libero vitae mi viverra tincidunt vitae ac purus. Pellentesque ac justo et augue tincidunt maximus. Morbi velit metus, consectetur ac orci sit amet, gravida suscipit lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur est leo, rutrum eget laoreet at, imperdiet id velit. Phasellus dignissim mi sed lacus porttitor tempor et tempus justo. Aliquam at congue augue. Quisque sed velit ac neque tristique sagittis. 
    Relocation is NOT a problem.
    \NewPart{Skills}{}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
            \item 4
            \item 5
            \item 6
            \item 7
            \item 8
            \item 9
            \item 10
            \item 11
            \item 12
            \item 13
            \item 14
        \end{itemize}   
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, I see your answer is good in this case. But how to make figures(float) at the top right of the page surrounded by text all the time?